# How to include available gradle library in Nativescript angular app?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I know that it is possible. But  i am not getting any starightcut and easily understandable implementation for it. Is it require to make a Nativescript plugin or Can i use it directly? If i make a temporary plugin then does it enough to only make a include.gradle file in android platform of plugin directory and add gradle dependency to that include.gradle???

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to write a plugin if you want to just access the native library within your project. You may directly add the dependency in your `app.gradle` file and start using the native apis in your project.

To avoid TypeScript compiler errors, declare your native methods Or optionally generate typing for your library. Read more on [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/metadata/generating-typescript-declarations).

There is no specific procedure you have for Angular, the steps are common across flavours.